# How to expand an abbreviated date into a full date?

Tags: vim

I use vim for accounting with ledger.  I'd like to be able to enter a date at the beginning of a line like this:

`4/3`

and then, after pressing `space`, have it auto-expand to this:

`2017/04/03`

What is the best way to accomplish this in vim?

Comment: The vim wiki has several tips on how to [insert the *current* date](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Insert_current_date_or_time).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `inoremap <expr>` is what you are looking for. And `printf` and `substitute` can help you to build the datetime format. Put them together:

```
inoremap <expr> <space> match(getline('.'), '\v^\d\d?/\d\d?') == -1? " ": '<Esc>v0s'.substitute(getline('.'), '\v^(\d\d?)/(\d\d?)', "\\=printf('%s/%.2d/%.2d',strftime('%Y'),submatch(1),submatch(2))","")
```

A little Demo:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps better ways exist but following find and replace would do the trick *(and you can always create a mapping for it)*

```
:%s#\v^(\d{1,2})/(\d{1,2})#\=printf('%4s/%1.2d/%2.2d', strftime('%Y'), submatch(1), submatch(2)
```

)

**Breakdown** *(edited: kudo's to Roland)*

```
%s#              
   - Starts a find and replace. Use # as separator

\v^(\d{1,2})/(\d{1,2})   
   - Search from the start of the line for one or two digits, folowed by a /, followed by a one or two digits.

\=printf('%4s/%1.2d/%2.2d', strftime('%Y'), submatch(1), submatch(2)) 
   - Replace matched items using a formatstring, padding zero's if necessary. Insert the current year with `strftime`.
```

Comment: I wonder if it wouldn't be better to use `\{1,2}` instead of `*` for the numbers?

Comment: @RolandSmith - Yes, offcourse :). If you have any other tips, feel free to improve the answer.

Comment: Used `strftime` to insert the current year. That's about as good as is will get with a simple regex, I think. One could write a vimscript function that validated the month and days and use that in the regex, but that might be overkill.